# UIButton change dimensions at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I have a xib file of UIView which has 2 buttons in it. Like this :
[image]

Button1 will be either hidden on shown. When it is hidden I want other button to take away whole space.
I also want the view to occupy all available space (orientation change also to be managed). In IB for view, I have selected Size as `Freeform`, Orientation as `Portrait`.
For that I added Constraints to both buttons setting 0 to top, bottom and left/right. But with this, when orientation is changed their is gap between both the buttons which I don't want.

I tried many ways but am not able to handle the above two matters. Both are also inter-related. If Button1 is hidden, then should add left constraint to other button also. Right now, I have removed all constraints, so in landscape it doesn't utilize full space.

Can you let me know how do I handle this inter-related issues.

**UPDATE** 
Added the following method to the view (UIView) class. Adding it like this is new for me, with reference have written code to add for top, bottom and left/right setting 0 on both buttons. Left with main role - button1 is hidden then what to add and shown then what.

```
-(void) addCustomConstriants:(BOOL) hideFirstBtn {

// http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/ui-design-of-ios-apps-with-autolayout-using-constraints-programmatically/2/

//NSDictionary *viewsDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.button1, self.button2);    
//NSArray *constriaints =

 if (hideFirstBtn) {
    // ONLY 2ND BUTTON - NO 1ST BUTTON

} else {
    // SHOW BOTH BUTTONS

    // BUTTON 1
    // ADD TOP CONSTRAINT - 0
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0] ];

    // ADD BOTTOM - 0
    [self addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0 ]  ];

    // LEFT
    [self addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0 ]  ];

    // BUTTON 2
    // ADD TOP CONSTRAINT - 0
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0] ];

    // ADD BOTTOM - 0
    [self addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0 ]  ];

    // ADD RIGHT - 0
    [self addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0 ]  ];

    // Width constraint, half of parent view width
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button1
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    multiplier:0.5
                                                      constant:0]];

    // Width constraint, half of parent view width
    [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.button2
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:self
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                    multiplier:0.5
                                                     constant:0]];

      // AFTER ADDING WIDTH ALSO FOR BOTH BUTTONS, WILL HAVE TO ADD X SOME HOW ??? PUZZLE ???
     }       
}
```

I believe I will also have to set Width for both the buttons. That should be of equal width. If only button2, then that width also will have to set here only right. How to add constraints for them ?

This is how I call this view from other screen :-

```
     vov1 = [visitorOptView objectAtIndex:0];
    // note the origin of the frame is (0, 0) since you are adding it to the cell instead of the table view
    vov1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, selectedCell.frame.size.width, selectedCell.frame.size.height);
    btnWidth = selectedCell.frame.size.width;

    [vov1.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(showVisitorDetailsView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // show/Enable "Start Chat" btn, else Disable it
    if (tableView.tag == 0 || tableView.tag ==1) {
        // START
        [vov1.button1 setTitle:@"Accept" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [vov1.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(acceptBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    } else if (tableView.tag == 3) {
        // CLOSED LIST - HIDE ALL BTNS
        [vov1.button1 setHidden:YES];
    }

    ///// HERE addCustomConstraints SHOULD BE CALLED I THINK

    // add overlay view to this row
    [selectedCell.contentView addSubview:vov1];
```

Can you help me with the above.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should add the constraints by code. So when the two buttons are shown. the first button trailing constraint should be bonded to the leading to the second button constraint. If the "View Details" button is the only one shown then hide the first one and the leading constraint to that button will be bonded with the leading of the self.view .
Create a method called `addCustomConstraints` and call it in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I have created method and added above. Can you please check it and help me with the remaining. I am bit new in coding and also using constraints.  Thanks.

Comment: First you constraints are wrong. In 'To item:' you pass self, but you should pass self.view if the constraint is bonded with the view or self.button if the constraint is bonded with the left button. Second, adding the constraints should happen in the if/else statement. If the button is hidden the app should add one group of constraints, if not the others.
// LEFT
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.viewDetailsButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0 ]];

Comment: Don't use [self button], since button is not a method.
Add the code above in the if statement.

Comment: I made changes in [self button1] changed to self.button1 . Secondly, my class is already a subclass on UIView and have 2 buttons directly in it. I can't get self.view.

Comment: I have updated the method, can you please have a look at it. For if() part, as button1 will be hidden so their will be no need to add any constraints for it or what ???

Comment: No matter if you button is hidden or not, you have to add constraint in the if part. Before adding them remove all of them. [self.button1 removeAllConstraints]. For simplicity open new project and add only one button and see what constraints you use, and also add two buttons and see what constraints you use. Copy them in code.